# Easy way to separate HTML from PHP code

Tags: php

I would like to separate the html and just use echo for easier further styling/editing this html snippet, like this

```
<li>
  <a href="<?php echo $filepath; ?>"><?php echo $file; ?></a>
</li>
```

Here is my current code that works, but I can not easily edit the html inside the PHP code

```
<?php

$dir = ".";
$exclude = array( ".","..",".*","*.php" );
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    $files = scandir($dir);
    foreach($files as $file){
        if(!in_array($file,$exclude)){
            $filepath = str_replace(' ', '%20', $file);
            echo '<li><a href=' . $dir . '/' . $filepath . '>' . $file . '</a></li>';

        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: You should look into a PHP templating setup - `laravel` uses blade, for example.

Comment: also, short hand for an echo in PHP is `<?=$var?>`

Comment: Can you be more specific with `easily edit`? What are you trying to do and what happens when you do it?

Comment: Maybe you could look into the mvc design pattern and after that use some kind of templating library (blade, twig, whatever)

Comment: FYI, your `.*` and `*.php` patterns in `$exclude` will not match files in the `$files` array via `in_array`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I highly recommend [PHP's alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) for templating. For example

```
$dir = ".";
$exclude = array( ".","..",".*","*.php" );
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    $files = array_diff(scandir($dir), $exclude);
    foreach ($files as $file) : ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?= $dir ?>/<?= urlencode($file) ?>">
            <?= $file ?>
        </a>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach;
}
```

Comment: thanks Phil, that was exactly what I was looking for :)